# order by only one dataset of a union in a tsql union of datasets

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by, union

I have the following problem.

Let TableA(Id int, Name nvarchar(200)) and TableB(Id int, Name nvarchar(200)).

If we run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM TableA) 
UNION
(SELECT *
 FROM TableB)
```

we get the union of the two datasets.

My Problem is that I want the results of the second dataset to be the ordered by the Name column.

The reason why I need this, is the fact that TableA is a temporary table in my query, that always will hold one record, and this record I want to be the first in the resulting dataset from the union of the two datasets. Also, I want the multiple records of the TableB to be ordered by the Name column.

Unfortunately, when I try to execute the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM TableA) 
UNION
(SELECT *
 FROM TableB
 ORDER BY Name)
```

I get an ambiguous error message, that informs me that I have an incorrect syntax near the keyword order.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "this record I want to be the first in the resulting dataset" - then you had better have something in your `ORDER BY` clause that causes that to happen. There is **no** guarantee that the results from the first `SELECT` will appear before (and not after, or mixed together) with the results from subsequent `SELECT`s when using a `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`) operator.

Comment: When you say something in my ORDER BY clause, what do you mean?

Comment: That you need an `ORDER BY` clause that applies to the *entire* result set, and considers the results from *all* of the `SELECT` statements in the union, and specifies *all* of your ordering requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
select id 
     , name
  from
(select 1 as ordercol
      , a.id
      , a.name
   from tableA 
union
 select 2 as ordercol
      , b.id
      , b.name
   from tableB) i
order by ordercol, name
```

the error message resulted in you trying to union two subselects. you can put union between two selects that will then be put into a subselect. there is always a select after a union (or union all). i would also suggest you use a union all, that saves time because sql-server will otherwise try and remove records that are in both selects (which in this case is impossible due to the ordercol-column)

i have included a second order-by column that will order the first select before the second. if you order by that first and then by name, you should get the desired result.